# Can't find "Target framework" option in VS2010 VB Project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, target-framework

I have created a new VB.NET Windows Forms Application.

In VS2010 I click the project settings, and I see the regular tabs "Application", "Build", "Build events", etc.

But under tab "Application", there is no option named "Target framework" like in the following shot:

[image]

It is simply not there for me. 
Instead the option "Application type" is shown at that location.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of VS 2012? Express, Pro, ...? And maybe you should give an image of how it DOES look ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your screenshot shows where the option exists for C# projects.  For VB projects, you can follow the MSDN directions here:

- [How to: Target a Specific .NET Framework Version or Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202(v=vs.100).aspx)

Basically:

- Compile Tab -> Advanced Compile Options...

[image]

Comment: Using VS 2012 Premium, I can choose the target framework for a VB Windows Forms App on the "Application" pane ... (directly below "Assembly Name")